# Not able to access static files in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I tried to use my fonts folder files inside one of my controller files. fonts folder is inside the public folder. I checked some of the StackOverflow questions and add this code to my app.js file. but somehow it didn't work for me.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

here is the controller file code in which I try to access these files.

```
var fonts = {
  Roboto: {
    normal: '/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf',
  }
};

var PdfPrinter = require('pdfmake');
var printer = new PdfPrinter(fonts);
```

This is the error I got when I run the server.

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf'
```

Comment: What is the request's URL that gives you 404? You can track these in browser's console.

Comment: Is the controller code client-side? Have you looked at the browser's developer tools' Network tab to determine what URL it is actually asking for? Is that URL the one you expect? What is the actual path to the file you are trying to read? What is the path to the file you are using __dirname in?

Comment: This code is for the server side.  My node server crashed by giving an error of missing file and directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static end point is only going to apply when clients read URLs from the server. It has nothing to do with other server-side JS that reads directly from the filesystem.

You need to use an absolute path (which you could compute relative to the directory the JS file is in with `__dirname` just like you did when setting up the static end point.